# why prefix index is slower than index in mysql?

Tags: mysql, indexing, sql-optimization

table:(quantity：2100W)

```
CREATE TABLE `prefix` (
  `id` int(11) unsigned NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `number` int(11) NOT NULL,
  `string` varchar(750) NOT NULL DEFAULT '',
  PRIMARY KEY (`id`),
  KEY `idx_string_prefix10` (`string`(10)),
  KEY `idx_string` (`string`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4;
```

discrimination:

```
select count(distinct(left(string,10)))/count(*) from prefix;
+-------------------------------------------+
| count(distinct(left(string,10)))/count(*) |
+-------------------------------------------+
|                                    0.9999 |
+-------------------------------------------+
```

result:

```
select sql_no_cache count(*) from prefix force index(idx_string_prefix10) 
where string <"1505d28b"
243.96s，241.88s

select sql_no_cache count(*) from prefix force index(idx_string) 
where string < "1505d28b"
7.96s，7.21s，7.53s
```

why prefix index is slower than index in mysql?（forgive my broken English）

```
explain select sql_no_cache count(*) from prefix force index(idx_string_prefix10) 
where string < "1505d28b";

+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
| id | select_type |  table | partitions |  type |       possible_keys |                 key | key_len |  ref |    rows | filtered |       Extra |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
|  1 |      SIMPLE | prefix |       NULL | range | idx_string_prefix10 | idx_string_prefix10 |      42 | NULL | 3489704 |   100.00 | Using where |
+----+-------------+--------+------------+-------+---------------------+---------------------+---------+------+---------+----------+-------------+
```

Comment: Can you show the `EXPLAIN` output? I'd also wager a wild guess that the prefix index is not selective enough.

Comment: I use the force index , the explain shows the key is prefix index

Comment: I copied your EXPLAIN output into the question above, because it was unreadable in a comment.

Comment: Yet another example of why "prefix" indexes are virtually useless.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

When you use a prefix index, MySQL has to read from the index and also after reading the index, it has to read the row of data too, to make sure the value is selected by the WHERE condition. That's two reads, and scanning a lot more data.

When you use a non-prefix index, MySQL can read the whole string value from the index, and it knows immediately whether the value is selected by the condition, or if it can be skipped.

Comment: It means that when the query uses the prefix index,it must read the row of data, if the engine is innodb ,it will scan the cluster index?

Comment: @NapsterLong - The secondary index implicitly has `id` in it.  It will use `id` to drill down the BTree for the clustered index.  (Drilling down a few levels is really fast; "scanning" is much slower.)

Comment: if my prefix index is 10 ,and the sql like " select count(*) from table where string < "aa"(the where condition length less than 10),is it need to read the row of data to make sure the value?

Comment: Logically, we know that a value in the table like 'zzzzzzzzzzzz' is in fact < 'aa' and we don't need to examine the part of the data beyond the prefix index. But the code in MySQL is not necessarily that clever.

Comment: thanks a lot, but I also want to know why mysql can't optimize it, maybe it will be fast in some condition .(Is it because the mysql's architecture that can't do this?)

Comment: It's because of MySQL's implementation.